# Add tag method in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to change the format of a string selected by the user in a Text widget called "Auftrag_entry" to bold and red and displaying the result in another Text widget called Textbold. The text appears in Textbold, but the format doesn't change. Any ideas ?

```
def print_in_bold():

Textbold = Text(Frame_Upper_Menu, width=20, height=1, bg="#ffffff")
Textbold.grid(column=6, row=0, pady=1, padx=1)

Textbold.tag_configure("BOLD", font="bold", foreground="red")

Auftrag_entry_selection = Auftrag_entry.selection_get()
Auftrag_entry_selection_length = 1 + (len(Auftrag_entry_selection) -1) / 10

Textbold.tag_add("BOLD", 1.0, Auftrag_entry_selection_length)

Textbold.insert("insert", Auftrag_entry_selection)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I've been stuck on this since yesterday

Comment: You set the tag on a range that contained no text yet, so no characters had the tag applied to them.  Either do the `.tag_add()` after the `.insert()`, or simply specify the tag name as a third parameter to `.insert()`.

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

There is initially no data in your text widget, so `Auftrag_entry_selection` will be an empty string, the length will be zero, and thus you aren't applying the tag to anything.

If you're adding the tag at the same time you add the text, the simplest solution is to include the tag when calling `insert`:

```
Textbold.insert("insert", Auftrag_entry_selection, ("BOLD", ))
```